# Python: [PyTorch] Selectively add along axes without using a loop

Tags: python, pytorch

let’s say I have a Tensor X with dimensions [batch, channels, H, W]
then I have another tensor b that holds bias values for each channel which has dims [channels,]

I want y = x + b (per sample)

Is there a nice way to broadcast this over H and W for each channel for each sample in the batch without using a loop.

If i’m convolving I know I can use the bias field in the function to achieve this, but I’m just wondering if this can be achieved just with primitive ops (not using explicit looping)

[Link to PyTorch forum question](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/selectively-add-along-axes-without-using-a-loop/154020)

Answer (score 0):

`y =  x + b[None, :, None, None]` (basically expand b into x's axis template)